# How to change default value of combo box

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, combobox

I am trying to make SQL statement based on item selected throw combo box. I want to have default item selected as ID, but now it returns NULL.
What am I doing wrong?

```
private void Win_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myBox.SelectedValue = "ID";
   myBox.SelectedText = "ID";
   myBox.SelectedItem = "ID";

   myBox.Items.Add("ID");
   myBox.Items.Add("Name");
   myBox.Items.Add("Surname");
   myBox.Items.Add("Mobile"); 
}
```

Then in for SQL statement

```
MySQL.DisplayAndSearch("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE " + this.myBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + txt_Search.Text + "%'", dataGridView1);
```

Thank for any help :)

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to create an SQL command. Use parameterized statements. See [why it's a bad idea and how to fix it](//bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks for your comment I know about this problem but this is internal app that will use just 5 people so i guess it will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the item before inserting:

```
private void Win_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // first, add the items   
   myBox.Items.Add("ID");
   myBox.Items.Add("Name");
   myBox.Items.Add("Surname");
   myBox.Items.Add("Mobile"); 

   // now select it
   myBox.SelectedItem = "ID";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
        private void Win_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    
       myBox.Items.Add("ID");
       myBox.Items.Add("Name");
       myBox.Items.Add("Surname");
       myBox.Items.Add("Mobile"); 

// now select it
            myBox.SelectedIndex = myBox.FindString("Mobile");//id..etc
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).